# Getting "Connection refused" message while validating all links inside a page using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am using the below code to validate all broken links inside a page but i am getting error message

"*Connect to www.pilotflyingj.com:443 [www.pilotflyingj.com/74.114.188.63] failed: Connection refused: connect Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect*".

PFB the code I have used:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='featured-slider']/ul[1]"));
List<WebElement> links = table.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(links.size());

for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i++) {
    WebElement element = links.get(i);
    String url=element.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(url);
    verifyLink(url);            
}

public static void verifyLink(String urlLink) throws IOException {


    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlLink);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        System.out.println(urlLink+" - "+response.getStatusLine());
        }

}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get statuses from application where you need to log in?
If in selenium you log in to system then HttpClient can has a problem.

Comment: Hi @tomasz.myszka,

Yes.. I am trying to get the responses for all element having tagname as "a". So can you please suggest any other way.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I'm checking response header.
There is a sampler code:

```
protected static string GetResponseHeader(string url)
        {
            object response = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteAsyncScript(
                "var url = arguments[0];" +
                "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                "xhr.open('GET', url, true);" +
                "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
                "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
                "    callback(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());" +
                "  }" +
                "};" +
                "xhr.send();", url);

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
            return json;
        }
```

Also you can read about XMLHttpRequest in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest